# Sharing ADFS authentication across multiple domains

Tags: asp.net, ws-federation

I have a set of applications that could possibly be hosted under different domains or as sub-domains of a common domain.

All of these applications will authenticate against the same ADFS service.

**I want my application to automatically login, if another application has authenticated with the same ADFS service.**

For example, you only need to login into google once, and then if you visit any of their application sites ( Gmail / Google Drive / Google+ ), you are automatically logged into the application.

Hence, let's say we have an ADFS service **ADFS_AUTH_SERVICE**.

Application **Website1** authenticates with **ADFS_AUTH_SERVICE**.

User visits **Website2** which is also configured to authenticate with **ADFS_AUTH_SERVICE** .

Hence, **when user visits Website2 he should be automatically logged in**.

**UPDATE:** For more clarity, following is the sequence that is currently occuring:

**1.**  User enters `http://site1/Home`

**2.**  User is redirected to the online Microsoft ADFS authentication page.

**3.**  User enters his details and successfully authenticates with ADFS service and is redirected to `http://site1/Home`

**4.**  User's name is visible on `http://site1/Home`.

**5.**  User clicks on a link in site1 that takes him to `http://site2/Home`

***Expected Result:*** User's name should be visible on site2/Home

***Actual Result:*** User is redirected to the ADFS login page.

Answer (score 0):

This is how ADFS works. What I believe is your issue is that you have to understand that all **three** applications maintain their own authentications independently:

- WebSite1
- WebSite2
- ADFS

If you already have implemented a flow where WebSite1 forces users to be authenticated in ADFS then you have following situation:

- WebSite1 (already authenticated)
- WebSite2 (not yet authenticated)
- ADFS (already authenticated)

In order to automatically authenticate users in WebSite2, you just have to **force the authentiation flow** by requiring authorization on all possible requests which would be

```
 <authorization>
     <deny users="?" />
     <allow users="*" />
 </authorization>
```

for WebForms or

```
 [Authorize]
```

for MVC.

This way the WebSite2 that always required authentication will redirect to ADFS and ADFS will automatically redirect back, since the user is already authenticated there.

Unfortunately there is no magic flow to **check** if user is authenticated. All you can do is to initiate the passive (browser-based) flow. Note that if the user is not authenticated in ADFS in advance, the ADFS will ask the user for her credentials.

Comment: Right now I have set-up the same ADFS authentication for two different sites. I looged into site1 and then clicked on a link in site1 which redirected me to site2. As soon as I am redirected to site2, I am taken to the ADFS authentication page. As you've said I should've been redirected back and site2 should've displayed as the user logged-in. However, that does not happen. I am left on the ADFS site with the login page displayed. I am using the Microsoft ADFS service for authentication.

Comment: @ChrisSerrao: this sounds like your ADFS is misconfigured because that should **never** happen. ADFS issues its own cookie so assuming site1 also uses the very same ADFS (are you sure?), ADFS should not display the login page again. Which version of the ADFS and what's the contents of the `microsoft.identityserver.web` node in ADFS's `web.config`?

Comment: You're right. This issue should'nt have occurred. When I ran site from VS2013, it opened an instance of the IE browser and I logged into it. Then I ran a copy of that project from a different port registered as a different app on the same ADFS, and it opened another instance of IE and took me to the login page. However, after closing the applications and clearing the browser cache and history, I performed the same steps, however instead of logging into site2, I opened a new tab in the IE instance that was opened for site1 and visited site2 and I was automatically logged in.

Comment: AFAIK, browsers are supposed to share the cookies for the domain across tabs and instances. This particular behaviour that I noticed was very strange. There were no code changes or configuration changes made.

Comment: @ChrisSerrao: browsers share cookies between tabs but not instances.